# Adding path delimiter on autocomplete in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, autocomplete

In the Terminal on OSX, when you press Tab to autocomplete a directory name, a `/` delimiter gets added for you, so you can immediately type your next entry.

Is there a way to have the same behavior with `\` in the Windows default command prompt?

Autocomplete is there by default, but I need to manually type the `\`. In my preferred keyboard layout, this requires a combination of 2 keys, so it gets annoying when navigating to long paths.

If it makes any difference, this would be for Windows 10.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to to this in `cmd`. but I use [TCC/LE](https://jpsoft.com/all-downloads/downloads.html) instead: it provides many of the facilities of a Unix shell, but within the syntax of `cmd`. Among much else it has an option to append back-slash when `Tab` expands to a directory, just as you would like. Another work-round is to use one of several Windows implementations of Unix shells, including [win-bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/).